# ac3 incomplete frame at the end of files - false-positive error? How to get exact timecode of that error?

Tags: ffmpeg

I noticed that quite often I get the ffmpeg error about an incomplete frame for ac3. Besides the wording (isn't frame a term used only for video encodings?) I wonder that this seems to mostly happen at or close to the end of an input file usually. My impression is that it may be a false-positive error, because I do not notice issues with the sound during playback of the source and it feels like it might be intended that the last "frame" of an ac3 is incomplete, maybe because ac3 needs to have a length being a multiple of x or some other reason.

Questions:

1. Can someone verify or falsify my assumption? Is there something about ac3 causing "incomplete frame" in fully valid files under some specific circumstances (and which)?
2. Can I find out the precise position of the error? Best thing I found was to use
   "-v info -threads 1"
   to get
   "frame=.* fps=.* q=.* size=.* time=.* bitrate=.* speed=.*"
   output lines and with this estimate the position of the error.

Edit1:
using cpu  throtteling, the "-threads 1" idea can be improved on. As ffmpeg prints the status every second (I think) the information becomes more precise the slower the processing becomes. However this does obviously take very long to check. In my current test case I can now say that the error does not occur before the last second of duration.

Answer (score 0):

Some answers.

> isn't frame a term used only for video encodings?

No, it's also used in the context of streaming or data packaging. As for AC3, check out [its standard](https://www.atsc.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/A52-2018.pdf) and it defines its frame structure.

> Can I find out the precise position of the error?

You can try [ffprobe](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) with `-show_error`, `-show_packets`, or `-show_frames` option to see if it gives you a better info than ffmpeg call that you've tried.

Comment: ffprobe with all 3 options active and stdout and stderr merged does output a huge amount of information (~20% of the test file) but it ends with ffprobe header, metadata information and then the ac3 error. I do not think that this means that the error is in/after the last videoframe.

Comment: Oh yeah, I should've warn you of what it would output. So, the error is separately presented from the packet/frame info? That's too bad. (I wasn't 100% if it'd do what you wanted but I thought would be a good try.)

Comment: Noticeable It does not have an [ERROR]-section, even though the ffprobe documentation describes such a section. maybe ffprobe does only work for container structure errors?! -show_error option only does complete very fast, so it does not seem to analyze the actual streams.